# xlib marking a part of the screen

Tags: c, linux, gtk, xlib

I'm writing an application in xlib and gtk, what I would like to do is:
- change the cursor into crosshairs
- drag the mouse from x,y to x2,y, having a rectangle mark the area I'm marking on the screen
- report back with x,y and x2,y2

the first point is a little vague, but for the second point I can use XQueryPointer to query the location , so question in this part is how can I detect when the mouse button had been clicked and when it had been released

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to use both xlib and GTK at the same time. Doesn't GTK provide functionality for this?